# How to get Date(e.g like 2013-06-02) in the past based on input numbers of days (e.g like 230, 20 or 360 or whatever number of days) in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I want to get the date in the past based on numbers of days that input by user.

> e.g User entered 45 means calculate from the current day (2015-09-06)
>   back to the past to reached 45 days then what is that date of the
>   number 45?

How to achieve this in PHP please!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-45 days"));
?>
```

If you are taking the number from user through form or taking the number from variable

```
<?php
$days = "26"; //OR
$days = $_POST["inputName"];
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-".$days."days"));
?>
```

Comment: Work great!  Thank you very much, what I still don't know is the syntax

Comment: What syntax are you talking about?

Comment: I mean date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-".$days."days"));

Answer (score 1):

```
$date=date_create("2013-06-02");
date_sub($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("45 days"));
```

Initialize date like above or as howerver you want it and then pass that date object to the date_sub() function as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly achieve it from MySQL DB:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(date_field,INTERVAL 45 DAY) AS SubtractDate
FROM table_name;
```

Or

```
SELECT date(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 45 DAY)) SubtractDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this should work. But, you should search the web before asking here. That's the basic ABCD of anything. Hope you do that next time.

```
<?php
     echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-45 days'));
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!  Yeah, I tried so many times but I still can't get what I want so that's why I post it here

Answer (score 0):

echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-45days'));